# Merge Two files depending on a Column, nth occurrence of a string in the column of file 1 to be merged with nth occurrence

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files, merge

Merge Two files depending on a column, nth occurrence of a string in column1 of `file1` should be merged with nth occurrence of the same string in column1 of `file2`. I tried join but the results are not as expected.

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)| column -t | tac | sort | uniq > file3
```

**file1**

```
CAAX-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM
CAAZ-TEST-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM
DAA   oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM
DJF oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 6 CRM
DJF oracle.apps.appslogger 5 6 CRM
```

**file 2**

```
CAAX-MC CRMDomain
CAAZ-TEST-MC CRMDomain
DJF CRMDomain
DJF CommonDomain,CRMDomain,FinancialDomain
```

**file 3** -- desired output:

```
CAAX-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM CRMDomain
CAAZ-TEST-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM CRMDomain
DAA   oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM 
DJF oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 6 CRM CRMDomain
DJF oracle.apps.appslogger 5 6 CRMCommonDomain,CRMDomain,FinancialDomain
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L. What result do you expect? Would `join <(sort -r test) <(sort -r common_test.log) | uniq -w20` helps?

Comment: beside using `tac | sort | uniq` can be abriviated in `sort -u` (sort will rearrange result of `tac`, so tac is useless, and -u flag will make unique)

Comment: Thank you Costas. I would like the Result to be as in FILE 3. But  "join <(sort -r test) <(sort -r common_test.log) | uniq -w20" does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR-1]=$0} 
  FNR!=NR{for(i in a){split(a[i],x," ");
    if(x[1]==$1){$0=$0" "x[2];delete a[i];break}}print;}' file2 file1
```

Notice the argument order: `file2` is **before** `file1`.

- `FNR==NR`: applies only to the first file (in the arguments list): `file2`.

  - `a[NR-1]=$0`: fills an array `a` with the lines of `file2`.
- `FNR!=NR`: applies to `file1`.

  - `for(i in a)`: loop trough the prevously created array `a`
  - `split(a[i],x," ")`: split the value (line of `file2`) at the space and store it in the new array with name `x`.
  - `if(x[1]==$1)`: if the first element of `x` (`x[1]`) is equal to the first field (`$1`) of `file1` (if the first field is found in the array) then:
  - `$0=$0" "x[2]` set the line to be printed with the new value at the end `x[2]`.
  - `delete a[i];break` since you want the next occurence of that index when it appears again in `file1` (for example `DJF`), we need to delete that element of the array `a` and fall out of the for loop (`break`).
  - `print`: whether the element is found in the array or not doesn't matter, the line (of `file1`) should be printed anyway.

---

The output:

```
CAAX-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM CRMDomain
CAAZ-TEST-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM CRMDomain
DAA   oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM
DJF oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 6 CRM CRMDomain
DJF oracle.apps.appslogger 5 6 CRM CommonDomain,CRMDomain,FinancialDomain
```

Answer (score 0):

If files is ordered before try **awk**

```
awk '
    {
        a=$1                #store key field in var a
        b=$2                #store second field in var b
        do {
            getline <"test" #get line from test file
            if(l)           #if var l is not empty
                l=l"\n"$0   #add line to var l separated by newline
            else
                l=$0        #otherways(var l is empty) put line into var l
            }
        while(a!=$1)        #repeats above while key fields will be equal 
        print l,b           #prints stored lines + b part of first file
        l=""                #empty line store variable
     }' common_test.log
```

outputs:

```
CAAX-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM CRMDomain

CAAZ-TEST-MC oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM CRMDomain

DAA   oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 7 CRM

DJF oracle.log.ApplicationScript 1 6 CRM CRMDomain

DJF oracle.apps.appslogger 5 6 CRM CommonDomain,CRMDomain,FinancialDomain
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked.Can you explain the code briefly??